# Click Counter event listener to increment and decrement count. I need to make the count weighted

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a multi click counter that is coming together nicely. My JS code to increment and decrement is working fine. The two counters are added together to make total units. When the primary click counter goes up to the number nine the total units should increase to 1, 18 to 2 27 to 3 and so on. Also when the count goes down below 9 the unit total should be 0 again and so on. I know I need to use something along these lines `units = Math.floor(primaryNumber / 9);` but it returns NaN every time I try. I'll post my full code below but, if someone can explain to me how I can do this I would be so grateful.
So for example the primary result is 9 the total units = 1. Also if the primary result is 40 the total units should = 4
codepen link https://codepen.io/Jonbeckner/pen/GRGZLKM

JS code below

```js
let primaryNumber = document.querySelector(".primaryResult");
let primaryPlus =  document.querySelector(".buttonPrimaryp"); 
let primaryMinus =  document.querySelector(".buttonPrimarym"); 
let primaryReset =  document.querySelector(".primaryReset"); 
let units = document.querySelector("#totalUnits");
primaryPlus.addEventListener("click",function(){
  primaryNumber.innerText++;
  units.innerText++;
})
primaryMinus.addEventListener("click",function(){
  if (primaryNumber.innerText == 0) {
document.getElementsByClassName("primaryResult").innerText = "";
  }
  else {
  primaryNumber.innerText--;
  units.innerText--;
  }
})
primaryReset.addEventListener("click",function(){ 
  let priReset = Number(totalUnits.innerText) - Number(primaryNumber.innerText);
units.innerHTML = priReset;
  primaryNumber.innerText = 0;
})

let secondaryNumber = document.querySelector(".secondaryResult");
let secondaryPlus =  document.querySelector(".buttonSecondaryp"); 
let secondaryMinus =  document.querySelector(".buttonSecondarym"); 
let secondaryReset =  document.querySelector(".secondaryReset"); 
secondaryPlus.addEventListener("click",function(){
  secondaryNumber.innerText++;
  units.innerText++;
})
secondaryMinus.addEventListener("click",function(){
  if (secondaryNumber.innerText == 0) {
document.getElementsByClassName("secondaryResult").innerText = "";
  }
  else {
  secondaryNumber.innerText--;
  units.innerText--;
  }
})
secondaryReset.addEventListener("click",function(){
  let secReset = Number(totalUnits.innerText) - Number(secondaryNumber.innerText);
units.innerHTML = secReset;
  primaryNumber.innerText = 0;
  secondaryNumber.innerText = 0;
})
const weekday = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
const d = new Date();
let day = weekday[d.getDay()];
let id = day;
document.getElementById("buttonSave").addEventListener("click", function () {
  const total = Number(document.getElementById("totalUnits").innerText);
  if (total > 0) {
 document.getElementById(id).innerText = document.getElementById("totalUnits").innerText;}
  
  else {
    document.getElementById(id).innerText = "0";
  }
});


const FULL_DASH_ARRAY = 283;
const WARNING_THRESHOLD = 10;
const ALERT_THRESHOLD = 5;

const COLOR_CODES = {
    info: {
        color: "green"
    },
    warning: {
        color: "orange",
        threshold: WARNING_THRESHOLD
    },
    alert: {
        color: "red",
        threshold: ALERT_THRESHOLD
    }
}
let minutes = 120;
let TIME_LIMIT = minutes;
let timePassed = 0;
let timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
let timerInterval = null;
let remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;
let isRunning = false;

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<div class="base-timer">
  <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="base-timer__circle">
      <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
      <path
        id="base-timer-path-remaining"
        stroke-dasharray="283"
        class="base-timer__path-remaining ${remainingPathColor}"
        d="
          M 50, 50
          m -45, 0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
        "
      ></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <span id="base-timer-label" class="base-timer__label">${formatTime(
            timeLeft
        )}</span>
</div>
`;
//Start timer button
document.querySelector(".button-start").addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (isRunning) return;
    isRunning = true;   
  startTimer();
});
//Enter custom countdown time 
document.customForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  onTimesUp();
  let minutes = document.getElementById("minutes").value;
  const mins = this.minutes.value;
  TIME_LIMIT = mins * 60;
document.getElementById('minutes').value=null;
  startTimer();
});
//Reset button
document
    .querySelector(".button-start-reset")
    .addEventListener("click", function () {
        onTimesUp();
        resetTimer();
    });
//Reset timer
function resetTimer() {
    isRunning = false;
    const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT=120;
    document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(timeLeft);
    setCircleDasharray();
    document
        .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .classList.remove(warning.color);
    document
        .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .classList.remove(alert.color);
    document.getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining").classList.add(info.color);
}
//Times up
function onTimesUp() {
    clearInterval(timerInterval);
}
//Start timer
function startTimer() {
    timePassed = 0;
    timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
        timePassed = timePassed += 1;
        timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
        document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(timeLeft);
        setCircleDasharray();
        setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);

        if (timeLeft === 0) {
            onTimesUp();
            resetTimer();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function formatTime(time) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    let seconds = time % 60;

    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = `0${seconds}`;
    }

    return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

function setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft) {
    const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
    if (timeLeft <= alert.threshold) {
        document
            .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
            .classList.remove(warning.color);
        document
            .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
            .classList.add(alert.color);
    } else if (timeLeft <= warning.threshold) {
        document
            .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
            .classList.remove(info.color);
        document
            .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
            .classList.add(warning.color);
    }
}

function calculateTimeFraction() {
    const rawTimeFraction = timeLeft / TIME_LIMIT;
    return rawTimeFraction - (1 / TIME_LIMIT) * (1 - rawTimeFraction);
}

function setCircleDasharray() {
    const circleDasharray = `${(calculateTimeFraction() * FULL_DASH_ARRAY).toFixed(
        0
    )} 283`;
    document
        .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", circleDasharray);
}
```

```css
body {
    background: #000000;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
        Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.block-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.primaryResult, .secondaryResult {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    font-size: 100px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

button{
    display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.plusminus {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}
.tile {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 375px;
    height: 425px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: solid;
  border-width: 6px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 20px;
}

.button {
    margin-top: 40px;
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
    font-size: 32px;
}

.buttontimer {
    margin-top: 40px;
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    padding: 4px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
    font-size: 32px;
}

input {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    padding: 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
}

.button:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.button[disabled] {
    opacity: 0.7;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.buttonPrimaryp, .buttonPrimarym  {
  display: block;
    background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.buttonSecondaryp, .buttonSecondarym {
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.primaryReset, .secondaryReset,.buttonReset {
    background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    margin: 12px auto 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 4px 56px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

#app {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.button-start {
    background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    margin: 12px auto 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

.button-start-reset {
    background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    margin: 12px auto 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 4px 56px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}



.totaltile {
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
  border-width: 6px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
    font-size: 32px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#buttonSave {
    background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    margin: 5px 0;
  margin-left: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 4px 26px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

p {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    font-size: 32px;
}

.base-timer {
  margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.base-timer__svg {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.base-timer__circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke: none;
}

.base-timer__path-elapsed {
    stroke-width: 7px;
    stroke: grey;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining {
    stroke-width: 7px;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: 1s linear all;
    fill-rule: nonzero;
    stroke: currentColor;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.green {
    color: rgb(65, 184, 131);
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.orange {
    color: orange;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.red {
    color: red;
}

.base-timer__label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
}

.timerpadding {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

::placeholder {
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  text-align: center;
}

.weekdays {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    font-size: 32px;
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  
}

.weeklyTotals {
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  font-size: 16px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#sun, #mon, #tues, #wed, #thur, #fri, #sat{
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
    padding: 4px 15px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

#Sunday, #Monday, #Tuesday, #Wednesday, #Thursday, #Friday, #Saturday {
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="block-wrapper">
        <div class="tile">
            <div class="tile-block">
      <div class="primaryResult">0 </div>
        <p>Document Count</p>
                <span class="plusminus">
        <button class="button buttonPrimaryp" type="button">
                    +
                </button>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button class="button buttonPrimarym" type="button">
                    -
          </button> </span>
                <button class=" button primaryReset">
                    Reset
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile">
            <div class="tile-block">
        <span class="secondaryResult">0 </span>
                <p>Verified Videos</p>
                <span class="plusminus">
        <button class="button buttonSecondaryp" type="button">
                    +
                </button>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button class="button buttonSecondarym" type="button">
                    -
          </button> </span>
                <button class="button secondaryReset">
                    Reset
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile">
            <div class="tile-block">
                <div id="app">
                </div>
        <button class="button buttontimer button-start" type="button">
                    Start Timer
                </button>
        <form name="customForm" id="custom">
        <input type="text" id="minutes" placeholder="Enter Minutes" autocomplete="off">
      </form>
                <button class=" button buttontimer button-start-reset" type="button">
                    Reset
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    <span class="totaltile">
        <p>Total Units =&nbsp;
            <span id="totalUnits">
                0
            </span>
      <button id="buttonSave">
                    Save Total
                </button>
        </p>
    </span>
  <span class="weekTile">
  <div class="weeklyTotals">
  Weekly Totals
  </div>
<div class="weekdays">
  <span id="sun">
    <p>Sun</p>
    <span id="Sunday"> 0 </span>
  </span>
    <span id="mon">
      <p>Mon</p>
      <span id="Monday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="tues">
    <p>Tue</p>
      <span id="Tuesday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="wed">
    <p>Wed</p>
      <span id="Wednesday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="thur">
    <p>Thu</p>
     <span id="Thursday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="fri">
    <p>Fri</p>
      <span id="Friday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="sat">
    <p>Sat</p>
    <span id="Saturday">0 </span>
  </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I thought last time I helped you once with the same problem though, do you need my help again? @@

Comment: primaryNumber is an element not a number. Where in your code are you trying to use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse `primaryNumber.innerText` to a number and also need to use `secondaryNumber.innerText` for `units` calculation. You can try the below approach

```
primaryPlus.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const updatedPrimaryNumber = primaryNumber.innerText++;
  
  units.innerText = Math.floor(parseInt(updatedPrimaryNumber) / 9) + parseInt(secondaryNumber.innerText);
})
primaryMinus.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (primaryNumber.innerText == 0) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("primaryResult").innerText = 0;
  } else {
    const updatedPrimaryNumber = primaryNumber.innerText--;
    units.innerText = Math.floor(parseInt(updatedPrimaryNumber) / 9) + parseInt(secondaryNumber.innerText);
  }
})
```

```js
let primaryNumber = document.querySelector(".primaryResult");
let primaryPlus = document.querySelector(".buttonPrimaryp");
let primaryMinus = document.querySelector(".buttonPrimarym");
let primaryReset = document.querySelector(".primaryReset");
let units = document.querySelector("#totalUnits");
primaryPlus.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const updatedPrimaryNumber = primaryNumber.innerText++;
  
  units.innerText = Math.floor(parseInt(updatedPrimaryNumber) / 9) + parseInt(secondaryNumber.innerText);
})
primaryMinus.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (primaryNumber.innerText == 0) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("primaryResult").innerText = 0;
  } else {
    const updatedPrimaryNumber = primaryNumber.innerText--;
    units.innerText = Math.floor(parseInt(updatedPrimaryNumber) / 9) + parseInt(secondaryNumber.innerText);
  }
})
primaryReset.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let priReset = Number(totalUnits.innerText) - Number(primaryNumber.innerText);
  units.innerHTML = priReset;
  primaryNumber.innerText = 0;
})

let secondaryNumber = document.querySelector(".secondaryResult");
let secondaryPlus = document.querySelector(".buttonSecondaryp");
let secondaryMinus = document.querySelector(".buttonSecondarym");
let secondaryReset = document.querySelector(".secondaryReset");
secondaryPlus.addEventListener("click", function() {
  secondaryNumber.innerText++;
  units.innerText++;
})
secondaryMinus.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (secondaryNumber.innerText == 0) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("secondaryResult").innerText = 0;
  } else {
    secondaryNumber.innerText--;
    units.innerText--;
  }
})
secondaryReset.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let secReset = Number(totalUnits.innerText) - Number(secondaryNumber.innerText);
  units.innerHTML = secReset;
  primaryNumber.innerText = 0;
  secondaryNumber.innerText = 0;
})
const weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
const d = new Date();
let day = weekday[d.getDay()];
let id = day;
document.getElementById("buttonSave").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const total = Number(document.getElementById("totalUnits").innerText);
  if (total > 0) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerText = document.getElementById("totalUnits").innerText;
  } else {
    document.getElementById(id).innerText = "0";
  }
});


const FULL_DASH_ARRAY = 283;
const WARNING_THRESHOLD = 10;
const ALERT_THRESHOLD = 5;

const COLOR_CODES = {
  info: {
    color: "green"
  },
  warning: {
    color: "orange",
    threshold: WARNING_THRESHOLD
  },
  alert: {
    color: "red",
    threshold: ALERT_THRESHOLD
  }
}
let minutes = 120;
let TIME_LIMIT = minutes;
let timePassed = 0;
let timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
let timerInterval = null;
let remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;
let isRunning = false;

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<div class="base-timer">
  <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="base-timer__circle">
      <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
      <path
        id="base-timer-path-remaining"
        stroke-dasharray="283"
        class="base-timer__path-remaining ${remainingPathColor}"
        d="
          M 50, 50
          m -45, 0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
        "
      ></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <span id="base-timer-label" class="base-timer__label">${formatTime(
            timeLeft
        )}</span>
</div>
`;
//Start timer button
document.querySelector(".button-start").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (isRunning) return;
  isRunning = true;
  startTimer();
});
//Enter custom countdown time 
document.customForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  onTimesUp();
  let minutes = document.getElementById("minutes").value;
  const mins = this.minutes.value;
  TIME_LIMIT = mins * 60;
  document.getElementById('minutes').value = null;
  startTimer();
});
//Reset button
document
  .querySelector(".button-start-reset")
  .addEventListener("click", function() {
    onTimesUp();
    resetTimer();
  });
//Reset timer
function resetTimer() {
  isRunning = false;
  const {
    alert,
    warning,
    info
  } = COLOR_CODES;
  timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT = 120;
  document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(timeLeft);
  setCircleDasharray();
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .classList.remove(warning.color);
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .classList.remove(alert.color);
  document.getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining").classList.add(info.color);
}
//Times up
function onTimesUp() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
}
//Start timer
function startTimer() {
  timePassed = 0;
  timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
    timePassed = timePassed += 1;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
    document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(timeLeft);
    setCircleDasharray();
    setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);

    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      onTimesUp();
      resetTimer();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function formatTime(time) {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }

  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

function setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft) {
  const {
    alert,
    warning,
    info
  } = COLOR_CODES;
  if (timeLeft <= alert.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(warning.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(alert.color);
  } else if (timeLeft <= warning.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(info.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(warning.color);
  }
}

function calculateTimeFraction() {
  const rawTimeFraction = timeLeft / TIME_LIMIT;
  return rawTimeFraction - (1 / TIME_LIMIT) * (1 - rawTimeFraction);
}

function setCircleDasharray() {
  const circleDasharray = `${(calculateTimeFraction() * FULL_DASH_ARRAY).toFixed(
        0
    )} 283`;
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", circleDasharray);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #000000;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.block-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.primaryResult,
.secondaryResult {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  font-size: 100px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.plusminus {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.tile {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 375px;
  height: 425px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 6px;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 40px;
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
  font-size: 32px;
}

.buttontimer {
  margin-top: 40px;
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
  font-size: 32px;
}

input {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
}

.button:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.button[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.7;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.buttonPrimaryp,
.buttonPrimarym {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.buttonSecondaryp,
.buttonSecondarym {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.primaryReset,
.secondaryReset,
.buttonReset {
  background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  margin: 12px auto 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 4px 56px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.button-start {
  background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  margin: 12px auto 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

.button-start-reset {
  background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  margin: 12px auto 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 4px 56px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

.totaltile {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 6px;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
  font-size: 32px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#buttonSave {
  background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  margin: 5px 0;
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 4px 26px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  font-size: 32px;
}

.base-timer {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.base-timer__svg {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.base-timer__circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
}

.base-timer__path-elapsed {
  stroke-width: 7px;
  stroke: grey;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining {
  stroke-width: 7px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 1s linear all;
  fill-rule: nonzero;
  stroke: currentColor;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.green {
  color: rgb(65, 184, 131);
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.orange {
  color: orange;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.red {
  color: red;
}

.base-timer__label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
}

.timerpadding {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

::placeholder {
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  text-align: center;
}

.weekdays {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.weeklyTotals {
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#sun,
#mon,
#tues,
#wed,
#thur,
#fri,
#sat {
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  padding: 4px 15px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

#Sunday,
#Monday,
#Tuesday,
#Wednesday,
#Thursday,
#Friday,
#Saturday {
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="block-wrapper">
    <div class="tile">
      <div class="tile-block">
        <div class="primaryResult">0 </div>
        <p>Document Count</p>
        <span class="plusminus">
        <button class="button buttonPrimaryp" type="button">
                    +
                </button>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button class="button buttonPrimarym" type="button">
                    -
          </button> </span>
        <button class=" button primaryReset">
                    Reset
                </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <div class="tile-block">
        <span class="secondaryResult">0 </span>
        <p>Verified Videos</p>
        <span class="plusminus">
        <button class="button buttonSecondaryp" type="button">
                    +
                </button>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button class="button buttonSecondarym" type="button">
                    -
          </button> </span>
        <button class="button secondaryReset">
                    Reset
                </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <div class="tile-block">
        <div id="app">
        </div>
        <button class="button buttontimer button-start" type="button">
                    Start Timer
                </button>
        <form name="customForm" id="custom">
          <input type="text" id="minutes" placeholder="Enter Minutes" autocomplete="off">
        </form>
        <button class=" button buttontimer button-start-reset" type="button">
                    Reset
                </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
  <span class="totaltile">
        <p>Total Units =&nbsp;
            <span id="totalUnits">
                0
            </span>
  <button id="buttonSave">
                    Save Total
                </button>
  </p>
  </span>
  <span class="weekTile">
  <div class="weeklyTotals">
  Weekly Totals
  </div>
<div class="weekdays">
  <span id="sun">
    <p>Sun</p>
    <span id="Sunday"> 0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="mon">
      <p>Mon</p>
      <span id="Monday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="tues">
    <p>Tue</p>
      <span id="Tuesday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="wed">
    <p>Wed</p>
      <span id="Wednesday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="thur">
    <p>Thu</p>
     <span id="Thursday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="fri">
    <p>Fri</p>
      <span id="Friday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="sat">
    <p>Sat</p>
    <span id="Saturday">0 </span>
  </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I could not understand the code the first time around. I had copied the original code from Codepen. This code I wrote myself based on my understanding. I am not looking to change how secondary number is handled only primary. When the primary number is decreased the total count should be adjusted.

Comment: I am able to figure out the solution from your code thanks for the help. I'll post my final solution in a bit.

Comment: oh great to hear that! @JonBeckner. I also really appreciate if you upvote my answer to give me a little support :D

Comment: my code is now working thanks @NickVu I took what you gave me and expanded upon it. Link to Codepen so you can see the updated code. codepen.io/Jonbeckner/pen/NWzdKoZ

Comment: Awesome! in terms of programming, I'm feeling you're getting better and better day by day :D @JonBeckner

Comment: Thank you I'm trying to learn as much as I can.